# How to connect multiple virtual machines hosted on the physical machine using kvm?

Tags: virtualization, kvm, virtual-network

I have been given a scenario in which multiple virtual machines are hosted by a same single physical machine. KVM is the hypervisor used for managing these virtual machines. How do I connect all the virtual machines to each other?

Comment: You could use libvirt to create a NATed or Bridged  network.

Comment: can you please explain or send me some links so that I'll get an idea about it?

Comment: And how can I do it using OpenVswitch?

Answer (score 0):

1. [libvirt NAT and Bridged](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking)
2. [libvirt supports openvSwitch as well](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/OVS_and_PVLANS)